# Postgres TDE capability only for specific schema

Tags: postgresql, tde

As part of GDPR requirement we need to encrypt data at rest.
We are planning to use Postgres and from the below links looks like TDE can be achieved in Postgres as well.

https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/postgres-and-transparent-data-encryption-tde
https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/products/postgresql-transparent-data-encryption/

When we have multiple schema in Postgres, is it possible to apply TDE only in a particular schema?

Comment: Why not just use an encrypted file system? (btw: I don't think GPDR _requires_ any encryption at all)

Comment: Why do you want to encrypt only one schema? What is the idea behind another one being unencrypted?

Comment: Can you please share the link with states GDPR does not require encryption of data at rest ?

Comment: There is only one schema which has PII details. Rest of the schema are not related to personal details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a reason for this: if we allow encryption on a per-table level (or per schema or per database, doesn't matter) we got to manage an infinite number of keys. this is especially true during point-in-time-recovery and all that. this is why we decided to do the encryption on the instance level. one key. the core advantage is: we can easily encrypt all parts of the instance including the WAL, temp files, and so on (basically everything but the clog).

don't expect this to change - go for full encryption.
we can help you with that.

cheers from cybertec :)
i hope you like the feature :)

hans

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it is not possible to just encrypt a schema because, when you install PostgreSQL TDE, you initialize the whole database with the encryption key.

Like you can see in the picture here:

[image: CYBERTEC PostgreSQL TDE]

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer